# Conjugate symmetric: 3D fourier transform dirmension

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, fast-wavelet-transform

I have a real value input 3D tensor with the shape of `(H,W,D)=[8,8,20]', where H, W, and D represent height, width and depth in (z dimension), respectively. When converting to the DFT, what will be the dimension of the DFT complex tensor (3D Fourier Transform)?

I read in one article that 2D Dft becomes like the following due to the conjugate symmetry:

what about 3D input real array? what will be the DFT tensor size

Answer (score 0):

In many software packages (like Python's [scipy.fft.fftn](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fftn.html#scipy.fft.fftn)), the DFT/FFT of an N-dimensional array will be the same shape as the input. If you specify an output shape (equivalent to the "n" or "nfft" argument for a 1-D FFT), you can change the number of frequency bins that are calculated for each dimension. For any dimension, an output length that is longer than the input is performing zero-padding and an output length that is shorter than the input is cropped.

A typical FFT will calculate both the negative and positive frequencies of the input. See the [documentation for fftfreq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fftfreq.html#scipy.fft.fftfreq) for an idea of what frequencies would be used for a given input dimension length.*

Mathematically, the frequency content of a real-valued signal has conjugate symmetry across positive and negative frequencies, meaning the amplitudes are the same ($|X(f)|=|X(-f)|$), but the phases are negated ($\angle X(f)=-\angle X(-f)$). If you know a priori that your input is real-valued, you can take advantage of an algorithm that is faster than the usual FFT because it only calculates the one side of the spectrum. In scipy, this is the [rfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.rfft.html#scipy.fft.rfft) function (or [rfftn](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.rfftn.html#scipy.fft.rfftn) for multidimensional inputs). The associated frequency vectors for the outputs of the rfft, or of a single dimension of the rfftn, can be found with [rfftfreq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.rfftfreq.html#scipy.fft.rfftfreq).

*Note that the frequency ordering of fftfreq is kind of squirrely. This is because it's output matches frequencies proceeding counter-clockwise around the unit circle. If you want to plot a linearly increasing frequency vector (negative Nyquist to positive Nyquist), perform an [fftshift](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fftshift.html#scipy.fft.fftshift) on both the frequency vectors you calculate with fftfreq and the output data calculated with fftn.

Though I've only included references to Python's scipy package, these functions are implemented in other languages too, possibly with slightly different names.